# How to post another row data in php based on session?

Tags: php, sql

I have a login code like this :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    include("koneksi.php");

    $username   = $_POST['username'];
    $password   = md5($_POST['password']);
    $level      = $_POST['level'];

    $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Upss...!!! Login gagal.</div>';
    }else{
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

        if($row['level'] == 1 && $level == 1){
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['level']='admin';
            header("Location: user.php");
        }else if($row['level'] == 2 && $level == 2){
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['level']='dosen';
            header("Location: user.php");
        }else if($row['level'] == 3 && $level == 3){
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['level']='mahasiswa';
            header("Location: user.php");
        }else{
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Upss...!!! Login gagal.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And i want to post users name not the username based on session in the user.php file, what should i do?

and this the user.php :

```
<div class="login">
    <p>Login Succes</p>
    <p>Username: <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?><br>
    Level: <?php echo $_SESSION['level']; ?></p>
    <p><a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')">Log out</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the column name that stores this value?  Is it `user`?

Comment: Although not on topic I'd urge you to 1) escape your data to prevent SQL injection and 2) beef up your password encryption. MD5 is not suitable

Comment: And use `htmlentities` when outputting user data to prevent XSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the user's name is stored in a database column called `name`, you could save this value to a session variable and display it to the user like so:

Login code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    include("koneksi.php");

    $username   = $_POST['username'];
    $password   = md5($_POST['password']);
    $level      = $_POST['level'];

    $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Upss...!!! Login gagal.</div>';
    }else{
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

        if($row['level'] == 1 && $level == 1){
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['level']='admin';
            $_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
            header("Location: user.php");
        }else if($row['level'] == 2 && $level == 2){
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['level']='dosen';
            $_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
            header("Location: user.php");
        }else if($row['level'] == 3 && $level == 3){
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['level']='mahasiswa';
            $_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
            header("Location: user.php");
        }else{
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Upss...!!! Login gagal.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Display code:

```
<div class="login">
    <p>Login Succes</p>
    <p>Username: <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?><br>
    Name: <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?><br>
    Level: <?php echo $_SESSION['level']; ?></p>
    <p><a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')">Log out</a></p>
</div>
```

Now, if the user's name is actually stored in 2 columns, for example `first_name` and `last_name`, then you could save it to the session like so:

```
$_SESSION['name']=$row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];
```